# Convertir las letras de una palabra ingresada por el usuario a mayúsculas

Tags: c, string

Me han dejado una tarea en la universidad en la que tengo que solicitar una palabra en minúsculas al usuario y regresar la misma palabra pero en mayúsculas. No tengo mucha experiencia en programación. ¿Alguien me podría ayudar con el código por favor? El 255 es porque trabajamos con cadenas hasta de 255 caracteres

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{

    int i;
    char palabra[255];
    {
        printf("Ingrese una palabra en minusculas: \n");
        scanf("%s",palabra);
    }

    for(i=0;i<255;i++)
    {
        if(palabra[i]>='z' && palabra[i]<='z'){
            palabra[i]-=32;
        }
        else if
        (printf("La palabra debe estar en minúsculas"));
    }
    printf("%s",palabra);
}
```

Comment: Revisa esa condición del if. Que sea mayor o igual a 'z' **y además** menor o igual a 'z'. Eso solo se cumple para cuando sea 'z'

Answer (score 2):

Tienes una serie de problemas en tu código, por orden:

1. No es necesario pre-declarar las variables de bucle fuera del bucle, puedes hacerlo en el propio bucle, en lugar de esto:

   ```
   int i;

   ...

   for(i=0;i<255;i++)
   {
   ```

   Esto:

   ```
   for(int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
   //  ^^^^^ <--- declarado aquí.
   {
   ```
2. Tu `else`-`if` no hace lo que crees.

   1. Para empezar, comparas letra a letra, así que la palabra "Patata", te escribiría al menos una vez que la palabra debe estar en minúsculas.
   2. No necesitas un `else`-`if`, no hay que controlar más de una posibilidad porque las palabras están o no están en mayúsculas.
   3. La impresión de mensajes no va dentro de `if`, seguramente querías hacer esto:

      ```
      if(palabra[i]>='z' && palabra[i]<='z'){
          palabra[i]-=32;
      }
      else {
          printf("La palabra debe estar en minúsculas");
      }
      ```
3. Debes añadir `return 0;` antes del cierre de `main`.

Dicho esto, tu código falla porque compruebas si una letra es mayor o igual a `'z'` o menor o igual a `'z'`, es decir, sólo te convierte las zetas. Seguramente querías hacer [esto](https://tio.run/##bY/LqsJADIb38xShom3xgnhwc9q6d@f@HBdxOtVATWWm40Lx2WscbwgmkBnyfyF/9Hirddf1iHXtSwO5a0tqJruFUsQt7JE4OTZUpuqsFEjoHVo4YI0bi3@z@XydhfbBCl4l0ZK31jgDnvFJgWHYE3unfY3uF/45Su9DTiPLTN9FowcrQlCqxia3/QQFTDN5cpBd8hkO0wCcQ70FVcnTDq0XRYwxDAbwbuVFfIrTNx/cvtRx8TPLXtpF3evHSV/sWdN6y@JMXbpuha2kugI):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    char palabra[255];
    printf("Ingrese una palabra en minusculas: \n");
    scanf("%s",palabra);

    for(int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
    {
        if(palabra[i]>='a' && palabra[i]<='z'){
    //                 ^^^ <- de a a z -> ^^^
            palabra[i]-=32;
        }
    }

    printf("%s",palabra);

    return 0;
}
```